# How to remove Border lines around sidepanel and main body content?

Tags: css, wordpress, double, border

I've been trying to get rid of borders around the body and widget areas of my site which came with the theme. Tried everything I know, to no avail. Here is a pic

Double borders around the body and side panel:

[image]

Is there some Custom CSS that could solve this?
Please help.

Comment: An image is not much help. Please include the the relevant HTML / CSS in your post, or at least link to the site.

Comment: Please post the source code. HTML + CSS.

Answer (score 0):

you could add a css line like below

```
* {border:none}
```

I hope, it may help you..